# Batch File to Loop Through Folders and Process If Specific File Found

Tags: batch-file, batch

I have a large number of websites running the same CMS that I want to update as a batch.  As the update process just requires copying the updated files into the folder of the given sites, a batch files seems suitable to the task.

Is there a good method for iterating through a list of folders one level deep (don't need to check deeper), checking if a specific file exists in that folder, and if found, run some commands (in this case, I will have it run a command to copy from a destination to the folder)?

Comment: Batch as in Windows batch?

Comment: Yes, Windows batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can use [Forfiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command ( It's native in Windows 7/2008/Vista and must install from Resource Kit in Windows Server 2003 ).

Just list all your folder in a text file. Then using a for loop to iteract each folder, feeding them to **Forfiles** command with `/p param`, search for specify filename with `/m param`. If matching, execute command with `/c param`.

Anyway, I advice you using some more powerfull tools like **PowerShell**.

Comment: That worked.

'forfiles /p "<basepath>" /s /m <file searched> /c "cmd /c call "%~f0" /callback @path"'

And then used @path

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running on? Something like this would work for Perl:

```
opendir DIR, $dirname or die "Couldn't open dir '$dirname': $!";
my @files = readdir(DIR); 
closedir DIR; 

foreach my $file (@files) {
   if ($file =~ /filename/) {
      print "Matched file process";
   }
}
```

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2